# How to convert the camera intrinsic matrix used by OpenCV to the camera projection matrix used by OpenGL?

Tags: opencv, opengl

To my knowledge, the process and matrix operation from the world coordinate system to the pixel coordinate system used by OpenCV are shown in the following figure:

[image]

But it seems that Opengl uses a different set, which also includes NDC coordinate system, UV coordinate system, etc., which is very different from what Opencv uses. Specifically, it seems that the matrix from the camera coordinate system to the pixel coordinate system used by Opengl is as follows :

[image] (from gsplat)

P.S. But for this projection_matrix, I have seen many versions online. What is the most accurate version?

---

So，If I take FX and fy out of the `OpenCV` internal parameter matrix and manually specify a distance from the far plane F and a distance from the near plane N, would I have completed the transition from opencv to opengl? And how do I get the exact value of n?

I need a conversion method from the matrix used by OpenCV to the matrix used by OENGL.